# Changing the Border Color of an Active Anchor Link on a Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm coding a navbar in Bootstrap. When an anchor link is active or selected, there is a border around it that is black and the resulting text is white. The goal is to make it so that there is no border/background color and the text is orange when it is selected instead of white. If you could provide some recommendations for how the code needs to be changed, that is greatly appreciated.

The image below illustrates what it looks like.

[image]

```css
nav {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  position: sticky;
  border: 0;
}

.nav-link {
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-link {
    margin-top: 1.0em;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}

.navbar-light .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-light .nav-item .nav-link:active,
.navbar-light .nav-item .nav-link:focus,
.navbar-light .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
  color: #FC9639;
}

.navbar-light .nav-item .nav-link:focus {
  background-color: white;
}

.icon-bar {
  background-color: #000000 !important;
  border: 0;
}

.navbar-light {
  background-color: white !important;
  border: none !important;
  border-width: 0!important;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-white navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>    
      </button>
      <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a> -->
      <a href="index.html"><img src="fusebloomLogo.png" alt="FuseBloom logo" class="logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#mission">Mission</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#reviews">Reviews</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#process">Process</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap?  And are you running/building with Sass?

Comment: I believe it's Bootstrap version 3. No, I am not building with Sass.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I've moved your code into an executable snippet with Bootstrap 3 added.  In this example, I see the nav item with an `.active` class has a black background and orange text, and when hovered the text becomes white.  This does not quite match your description: _"When an anchor link is active or selected, there is a border around it that is black and the resulting text is white."_.  Can you please specify the conditions needed to recreate the issue, perhaps include a screenshot or make sure they are reproducible here? The aim is a [mcve] in the question.  Thanks!

Comment: For what it is worth, the language _"When an anchor link is active or selected"_ is a bit ambiguous-- an [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) state is very specific, but I'm not clear that is what you mean, as there is also an `.active` class on the containing `li`, and "selected" is an ambiguous term could mean a number of things (if the `.active` class is present on the `li`, or when it is focused, or when it is being hovered, or when the user is actually currently clicking it, etc). Being specific would make the question easier to understand and answer.

Comment: Sure, @Alexander Nied, if there is an .active class on the containing li, that is what is meant by "selected."

Comment: Then in that case, the border/rectangle that surrounds it will be gone and instead the text will be white when it is hovered over.

Comment: When you say "border", do you mean the black background that fills the rectangle?  Or are you seeing a true border that outlines a black rectangle that is filled in white?  I don't mean to be difficult or pedantic, but what I am seeing in the snippet doesn't align with what I understand to be a [CSS border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border). A screenshot might be helpful here to understand exactly what you are seeing for clarity.

Comment: Look up at the top of the page. There, you will see an image of the navbar that has been added with the black background in question. Hope this helps! I appreciate you taking the time to understand.